# How do you downgrade a bigrat?

Tags: perl, bignum

```
perl -Mbigrat -E'for (1..100) { $i += 1/3; say int($i), "\t", sprintf "%.55f", $i }'
```

spams a lot of warnings:

```
Argument "100/3" isn't numeric in addition (+) at …/site_perl/5.24.1/Math/BigRat.pm line 1939.
```

Run again without `-Mbigrat` to see the desired effect of sprintf.

How do you downgrade the [`Math::BigRat`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigRat) instance `$i` into an ordinary [NV](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html) delectable to `sprintf`?

Versions:

- `bigrat` 0.47
- `Math::BigRat` 0.2612

Comment: FWIW bigrat @ 0.39 and Math::BigRat at 0.2608 do not have this warning. Upgrading bigrat to 0.47, which brings in Math-BigInt-1.999811, does have a warning, but it's `Use of uninitialized value in string eq at .../5.22.2/Math/BigFloat.pm line 3626.` Manually updating Math::BigRat gives me your warning.

Comment: Have you reported this problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

I expected `Math::BigRat` to provide a method for getting a plain number and it does:

- `as_int` for integers
- `as_float` for floats

I inserted printing of `$_` for debugging purposes.

`$i->as_int()` does the same as `int($i)`:

```
$ perl -Mbigrat -E'for (1..100) { $i += 1/3; say $_, "\t", int($i), "\t", sprintf "%.55f", $i->as_int() }'
...
99      33      33.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
100     33      33.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

`$i->as_float()` seemed to work as expected on first sight but I don’t understand the output. All decimal places are zero and for every second line `$i` equals `$_`:

```
$ perl -Mbigrat -E'for (1..100) { $i += 1/3; say $_, "\t", int($i), "\t", sprintf "%.55f", $i->as_float() }'
...
90      30      30.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
91      30      91.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
92      30      92.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
93      31      31.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
94      31      94.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
95      31      95.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
96      32      32.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
97      32      97.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
98      32      98.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
99      33      33.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
100     33      100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This is Perl 5.30.0 with Math::BigRat 0.2614.

So the warnings are fixed but there seems to be something wrong with this solution.

**Update:** As requested in the comments without `sprintf`:

```
$ perl -Mbigrat -E'for (1..100) { $i += 1/3; say $_, "\t", int($i), "\t", $i->as_float() }'
...
90      30      30
91      30      91
92      30      92
93      31      31
94      31      94
95      31      95
96      32      32
97      32      97
98      32      98
99      33      33
100     33      100
```

Comment: What if you leave out the sprintf and print `as_float` directly? It looks like what you're getting is the numerator of the fraction in reduced form, rather than the proper numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Not that serious of an answer:

```
use bigrat;
use feature 'say';
for (1..100) {
    $i += 1/3;
    no bigrat;
    say int($i),"\t",sprintf "%.55f", eval "$i"
}
```